# Using Zip to combine 3 strings instead of 2

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing a `Function` to add new `Nodes` to an `XML` file, so i created 2 `List<string>` and then combined them as following

```
var FirstText = FirstList;
var SecondText = SecondList;
var AllText = FirstText.Zip(SecondText, (t1, t2) => new { FirstWord = t1, SecondWord = t2 });
foreach (var tt in AllText)
{
    Xml.WriteStartElement(tt.FirstWord);
    Xml.WriteValue(tt.SecondWord);
    Xml.WriteEndElement();
}
```

to add something like this

```
<Force>True</Force>
<Auto>False</Auto>
```

right now i want to combine 3 `strings` instead of 2 by writing this

```
Xml.WriteStartElement(tt.FirstWord);
Xml.WriteStartElement(tt.SecondWord);
Xml.WriteValue(tt.ThirdWord);
Xml.WriteEndElement();
Xml.WriteEndElement();
```

so the `XML` would look like

```
<Settings>
  <Force>True</Force>
</Settings>
<Settings>
  <Auto>True</Auto>
</Settings>
```

how can i do such thing?

Comment: Type LinqToXml to google. You may find it easier to use than XmlWriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `.Zip` again:

```
var AllText = FirstText.Zip(SecondText, (t1, t2) => new { FirstWord = t1, SecondWord = t2 });
                       .Zip(Values, (t12, v) => new 
                           { FirstWord = t12.FirstWord, 
                             SecondWord = t12.SecondWord,
                             ThirdWord = v });
```

You could also